# deep learning data preparation

Tags: keras, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I have a text dataset, that contains 6 classes. for each sample, I have the percent value and sum of the 6 percent values is 100% (features are related to each other). For example :

```
{A:16, B:35, C:7, D:0, E:3, F:40}
```

how can I feed a deep learning algorithm with this dataset?
I actually want the prediction to be exactly in the shape of training data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

1. First of all, **normalize** all of your labels and scale them between 0-1.
2. Use a `softmax` layer for prediction.

Here is some code in `Keras` for intuition:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim = x.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```